# Infants tend to look longer at novel stimuli than at repeated stimuli, is this true in adults?

Tags: neuroscience, attention

I have recently read an [article](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/illusion-chasers/what-little-babies-see-that-you-no-longer-can/) in which it is stated, that the researchers can discriminate if a baby knows an object, by looking at the length of time the baby looks at the object. Do adults also tend to look longer to novel stimuli?

Comment: @Christiaan are you implying that “Is this feature true even for the adults?“ is more appropriate rather than "Is this feature also verifiable for adults?"

Comment: @JordiZambrino - yep imo. I changed it into a more appropriate sentence.

Comment: Good thing about migrated questions is I can upvote twice :-)

Comment: I will say that, while the habituation technique, which relies on this fact, is commonly used for babies, but I've never heard of an adult study using it. Take from that what you will.